# Conformal flatness of $\rm dS$ spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, de-sitter-spacetime

There exists a flat slicing in the lower triangle area of the Penrose diagram of $\rm dS$ spacetime.

To see this point, one introduces the planner coordinate, as defined in eq(13) of [Les Houches Lectures on De Sitter Space](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0110007), thus the line element becomes as
$$ds^2=-dt^2+e^{-\frac{2t}{\ell}}dx_idx^i\, .\tag{13}$$
As $t\rightarrow -\infty$, we approach the cosmological horizon, and this coordinate can just cover the lower triangle patch of $\rm dS$ (without the horizon boundary). From this coordinate, we can do better by introducing the **conformal time**
$$\tau=\ell e^{\frac{t}{\ell}}\,,$$
thus the line element deforms as
$$ds^2=\frac{\ell^2}{\tau^2}(-d\tau^2+dx^idx_i),$$
which implies $\rm dS$ is partly conformally flat, and the cosmological horizon is the conformal boundary of $\rm dS$ as $\tau\rightarrow 0$, as shown in the following diagram

[image]

There exists a conformal transformation between the upper diamond of flat spacetime and the lower triangle area of $\rm dS$.

**The cosmological horizon seems to be mapped to the equal $\tau$ surface in the flat spacetime.** As a fact the conformal transformation maintains the causal structure of spacetime. **The cosmological horizon is a null surface, while $\tau=0$ surface is a timelike in flat spacetime, which conflicts with the fact mentioned above.**

Is there something wrong?